# How do I do a paired test in gtsummary?

Tags: gtsummary

I have a list of continuous variables and I need to run them as a paired Wilcoxon test. I tried putting in all_continuous ~ "paired.wilcox.test" then it told me "Paired tests require the `group=` argument."

So I added the second line and now get an error "object 'class' not found."

How do I correctly give it the group argument?

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
library(tibble)

data<-tribble(
  ~icu, ~los, ~class,
  4, 6, 0,
  5, 8, 1,
  0, 2, 0,
  25, 50, 1, 
  3, 9, 0,
  11, 15, 1
)

data %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by=class,
    type = list(
      icu ~ "continuous",
      los ~ "continuous")
    ) %>%
  add_p(all_continuous() ~ "paired.wilcox.test",
        test.args = all_continuous() ~ list(group=class))
```

Comment: There are similar examples here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html#paired-test

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I wasn't telling it how the cases are paired to each other.  You have to tell it the variable that tells which cases are paired (in this case, "id")

Updated code:

```
data<-tribble(
  ~icu, ~los, ~class, ~id,
  4, 6, 0, 1,
  5, 8, 1, 1,
  0, 2, 0, 2,
  25, 50, 1, 2,
  3, 9, 0, 3,
  11, 15, 1, 3
)

data %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by=class,
    include = -id,
    type = list(
      icu ~ "continuous",
      los ~ "continuous")
    ) %>%
  add_p(test = list(
          all_continuous() ~ "paired.wilcox.test"),
        group = id)
```